# Regex to match whole word

Tags: regex

I saw many examples on stackoverflow regarding whole word match using Regex.
I have the following situation where I want to replace www.abc.com with www.xyz.com .

```
string RetVal = "I am going to visit www.abc.com";
string TextToFind = @"\bwww.abc.com\b";
string TextToReplace = "www.xyz.com";
bool IgnoreCase = true;
RegexOptions regOpt = RegexOptions.None;
if (IgnoreCase)
    regOpt = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
RetVal = Regex.Replace(RetVal, TextToFind,TextToReplace, regOpt);
```

above is working fine.But when I change

```
RetVal = "I am going to visit www.abc.com/xyz.html";
```

It is still replacing www.abc.com to www.xyz.com and I do not want to replace that.

Answer (score 2):

`\b` will match word boundaries, so any transition from a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) to a non-word character.

Since it sounds like you do not want to match if `/` follows your whole word, you are going to need a different boundary check.  Something like the following should work:

```
string TextToFind = @"(?<!\S)www.abc.com(?!\S)";
```

This will cause the match to fail if the character before your word is not whitespace, or if the character after your word is not whitespace.  Note that I used negative lookbehind/lookahead here instead of `(?<=\s)` and `(?=\s)` so that you will still match if your word is at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to have only white spaces or begin/end of line around your replaced string.

Use somehting like `(^|\s)string to replace(\s|$)`. Not sure what language you are using you may need to tune this string a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is a word boundary and will match where there's on one side a 'word' character (a word character here means a character that matches `\w`) and on another side a non-word character (that which matches `\W`).

If your definition of a whole word is 'something which has a space before and after it, unless it's at the beginning or at the end of the string', then you can use the regex:

```
(?<!\S)www.abc.com(?!\S)
```

To check exactly for this.

However, would you treat `www.abc.com` in those strings?

```
I'm going to visit www.abc.com; there's lots of things there.
What's this 'www.abc.com' you're speaking about?
```

If you still consider those as 'whole words', then maybe it'd better you only check for the main domain (i.e. there's no forward slash after `www.abc.com`):

```
\bwww.abc.com\b(?!/)
```

Then I guess your definition of 'whole word' is matching links with only the main domain name.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. \bwww.abc.com\b(?!/) would solve my problem